# Make three plot into one

Tags: r, plot

Having a code like this:

```
library(stm)
gadarian <- gadarian
K<-c(5,10,15)
temp<-textProcessor(documents=gadarian$open.ended.response,metadata=gadarian)
out <- prepDocuments(temp$documents, temp$vocab, temp$meta)
documents <- out$documents
vocab <- out$vocab
meta <- out$meta
set.seed(02138)
K<-c(5,10,15)
df1 <- searchK(documents, vocab, K, prevalence=~treatment + s(pid_rep), data=meta)
df2 <- searchK(documents, vocab, K, prevalence=~treatment + s(pid_rep), data=meta)
df3 <- searchK(documents, vocab, K, prevalence=~treatment + s(pid_rep), data=meta)
```

How is it possible to make the three following plot into one?

```
plot(df1$results$K,df1$results$semcoh, type = "b", 
     xlab = "Number of Topics (K)", ylab = "Semantic Coherence",
     main="Semantic Coherence")
plot(df2$results$K,df2$results$semcoh, type = "b", 
     xlab = "Number of Topics (K)", ylab = "Semantic Coherence",
     main="Semantic Coherence")
plot(df3$results$K,df3$results$semcoh, type = "b", 
     xlab = "Number of Topics (K)", ylab = "Semantic Coherence",
     main="Semantic Coherence")
```

What I tried is this:

```
plot(df1$results$K,df1$results$semcoh,
     ylim=range(c(df1$results$semcoh,df2$results$semcoh)),
     xlim=range(c(df1$results$K,df2$results$K)), type="b",col="red",
     xlab = "Number of Topics (K)", ylab = "Semantic Coherence",
     main="Semantic Coherence")

lines(df2$results$K,df2$results$semcoh,col="green", type="b")
lines(df3$results$K,df3$results$semcoh,col="blue", type="b")

# Add a legend
legend(5, -5.52, legend=c("score_1", "score_2", "score_3"),
   col=c("red", "green", "blue"), lty=1, cex=0.8, pch = 1)
```

but the problem is that it shows the last blue line.

From df3 only. How can I fix it?

Comment: You tagged with [tag:ggplot2] but I see `plot`, `lines`, and `legend`. I'm going to change from [tag:ggplot2] to [tag:plot], my apologies if there's something that I'm missing.

Comment: Nathalie, try typing `par(mfrow = c(2, 2))` into your console and running the three plots again. They should all appear on the same page.

Comment: Maybe change the `set.seed` value since `df3` probably contains the same result as `df2`.

Comment: @AllanCameron thank you. I tried but it didn't work.

Comment: @Edward what set.seed should I add set.seed(123)?

Answer (score 0):

When I run your commands, with a minor modification of the legend, after a few minutes I get the following plot:

[image]
Minor modification:

```
legend("topright", bty="n", ...)
```

And when I tried a variation of Allen Cameron's suggestion, I got the following:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,3), las=1, cex.axis=0.75, tck=-0.02, mgp=c(2,0.3,0))
plot(...) {...} # similar to your commands except no colour.
```

[image]

Comment: thank you. I run this option `legend("topright", bty="n", legend=c("score_1", "score_2", "score_3"),
   col=c("red", "green", "blue"), lty=1, cex=0.8, pch = 1)` but again I receive only the last line

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your problem. Can you show the image you get? ( edit your question )